# How Does isSelected work?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I currently launch a web page where I enter name, zip code then if the inputs are correct you're presented with second page where you need to click a check box and press a Submit button and finally you're presented with a third (final) page displaying "Thanks for Enrolling".

This code runs but nothing gets written to the log file. What's wrong?

```
Boolean b = driver.findElement(By.id("TermsCheckBox")).isSelected();
log.write("Checking Check Box Page - Expected: ", "https://www.mysite.com/Terms.html | Actual:  + driver.findElement(By.id("TermsCheckBox")).isSelected(), Desc);
```

Comment: There isn't enough to go on here. Please post a little more of the surrounding code (i.e what on earth is the `desc` variable?!) and the HTML of the controls you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite understanding the format of your log.write statement, but from what I can tell, isSelected() should work as you expect,

```
Boolean b = driver.findElement(By.id("TermsCheckBox")).isSelected();
```

`b` would be true/false depending on whether the checkbox is actually selected. As far as I know `isSelected()` is only relevant for checkbox & radio button inputs. Ensure that you do only have one element with the ID 'TermsCheckBox'

Comment: Selected is also relevant for options in a `select` element.